# Continuous function that equals 0 when 4 points form a square

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, continuity

Given the distances between four points that lie in $\mathbb{R^2}: a,b,c,d,e,f$

Is there a continuous function $g(a,b,c,d,e,f) \Rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $g = 0$ if and only if the four points form a square?

I know that it is true that when they form a square, some set of four of the distances will be equal and the other two distances will be equal to each other.

And I know that this formula:

$$\frac{d_1 + d_2 + d_3 + d_4}{d_5 + d_6}\cdot \left( \frac{\sqrt 2}2 \right) - 1$$

Will equal zero when the four points form a square, but I don't think that formula being zero implies the other direction nor am I convinced that it is continuous (or at least able to be analytically continued into a continuous function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can abuse some properties of the real numbers. First off, that the square of a non-zero number is positive. That means that if you want to check whether a collection of real numbers are all zero, you can just square them and add them. So, if we want $a = b = c = d$ and $e = f = \sqrt 2 a$, then we can just check whether the following holds:
$$
g_1(a, b, c, d, e, f) = (a-b)^2 + (a-c)^2 + (a-d)^2 + (e-\sqrt2 a)^2 + (f - \sqrt2a)^2 = 0
$$
Now, it might be that the distances do make a square, but that the configuration is wrong. For instance, we might have that $a = b = c = e$ and $d = f = \sqrt2a$. In that case, we would have to check
$$
g_2(a, b, c, d, e, f) = (a-b)^2 + (a-c)^2 + (a-e)^2 + (d-\sqrt2 a)^2 + (f - \sqrt2a)^2
$$
and so on, getting a lot of different $g_n$'s ($15$ of them, to be exact). Finally, since we're only interested in whether *one* of these hold, we use a second property of the real numbers: If the product of two numbers equals $0$, then one of the numbers have to be zero. Thus, if we set
$$
g(a, b, c, d, e, f) = g_1(a, b, c, d, e, f)\cdot g_2(a, b, c, d, e, f)\cdots g_{15}(a, b, c, d, e, f)
$$
then $g(a, b, c, d, e, f) = 0$ if and only if $g_n(a, b, c, d, e, f) = 0$ for some $n$, which only happens if that configuration actually represents the sides and diagonals of a square.

There is one problem with this, though: It doesn't check whether these numbers are *negative*. It just checks whether they are proportional and equal as they should be. This is most easily rectified by adding to all the $g_n$'s a term like $(a-|a|)^2$. That way, if the numbers turn out to be negative, none of the $g_n$'s will give zero.

Also, what happens if $a = b = c = d = e = f = 0$? Does that make a square? I don't know. It's not so easy to check for with nice and simple functions, though.

Comment: Thanks for saving me the trouble of  writing this :)  I don't think it is possible to exclude the case $a=b=c=d=e=f=0$ with a  **continuous** function because we clearly want $g(t,t,t,t,\sqrt2t,\sqrt2t)=0$ for all $t>0$. So, by continuity, we get a zero of $g$ with $t=0$ as well.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen We might introduce something like $(1-\frac aa)^2$ to make the $g_n$'s _undefined_ for $a = 0$, or even use $a^2+\cdots + f^2$ to make it undefined in only the origin, but in my opinion that would break too much of how this function _ought_ to work.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add that an application of law of cosines implies that if the set of distances is a scalar multiple of a permuted version of $(1,1,1,1,\sqrt2,\sqrt2)$, then the configuration is necessarily a square (only 90 and 60 degree angles are possible between two line segments of length $1$ sharing an end point et cetera).

Comment: For my purposes I suppose I should have added that all distances are assumed to be greater than or equal to 0. And that I'm also ok with the degenerate case of a=b=c=d=e=f=0. I'd edit the question, but it seems that this answer answers my question regardless.